# AWS credentials profile names vs user names

Tags: amazon-web-services

Creating an AWS IAM user typically includes creation of access-key-id and secret-access-key for identification of that user.  Putting these into the ~/.aws/credentials file requires an associated "profile" name.   If there is a one-to-one mapping of keys to users, why not put the user-name as the profile name? What purpose does it server to have them be different strings? How is this profile name used differently than the *user* name?

Comment: Profile name is just an alias. You can call it whatever you want.

Comment: Think of it as an alias for a set of credentials. You can name the alias anything you like. For example you might have an IAM user named `bfanse` in both your dev and prod AWS accounts so you could create two profiles: `bfanse-dev` and `bfanse-prod`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If there is a one-to-one mapping of keys to users [...],

There isn't.

An IAM User can have 2 Access Keys active at the same time. Not only that, but an IAM User can also generate any number of new, temporary Access Keys as well. Finally, there are Access Keys that are not associated with any IAM Users.

> [...] why not put the user-name as the profile name?

You definitely can. I'm not sure what led you to think you can't or shouldn't do it.

I rarely use IAM Users to authenticate to anything I do in AWS accounts, but when I do, I usually create *CLI configuration profiles* named in such a way that I know which account and user it is. EDIT: pretty similar to what @jarmod mentioned in a comment on your question.